# Wifi is not detected sometimes on android devices with OS Android 8.1 and above

Tags: android-wifi, android-jobscheduler

When a smartphone gets connected to wifi without internet, the job scheduler does not detect the wifi change and onAvailable method is not called sometimes. This issue is observed in android 8.1 OS and above smartphones.

This the code snippet used to detect the wifi connection.

The job is created on launch of the app in the launcher activity.

```
try {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, JobSchedulerWifi.class);
    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(12, componentName)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();

    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d("XXX", "Wifi_Job scheduled!"+jobInfo.getId());
    } else {
        Log.d("XXX", "Wifi_Job not scheduled");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}


public class JobSchedulerService extends JobService {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback;
    BroadcastReceiver connectivityChange;

    Context cont;
    private boolean jobCancelled=false;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters job) {
        Log.d("Job", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+"Job - Job created"+Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);

        cont=this;


        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            cont=this;
            connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                 //   super.onAvailable(network);
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) cont.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiInfo wifi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    String wificonnect =wifi.getSSID();
                    wificonnect = wificonnect.substring(1, wificonnect.length() - 1);

                    Log.i("job", "Default -> Internet Network Available"+wificonnect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using WorkManger?

WorkManager, part of Android X is supported back to API level 14 and makes detecting and running code on connection change a simple task.

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
    .build()

val myWorkRequest =
    OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>()
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(MyApplication.context).enqueue(myWorkRequest)
```

And the class that will be executed when the connection is detected:

```
class MyWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        doThis()
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun doThis() {
        Log.d("ASDF", "::onReceive")
    }
}
```

Additional resources:

- [Current library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work)

  [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)